# Do animals commit suicide?

Tags: zoology

Do we have documented cases of animals purposely and consciously trying to end their own life? What leads to animal suicide, and is it preventable?

I've heard mixed answers from various biologists. Is anyone here capable of providing an answer?

Comment: how much googling have you done on your own so far? that might be useful to know

Comment: @kmm, arguably the current question is different because of the vertebrate restriction and "purposely, consciously"

Comment: @ConnorSmith, they could get killed in the food chain, but I highly doubt they are *as mentally messed up as humans though*.